# Does the existence of a race condition in the code imply the existence of an execution sequence that will result in a deadlock?

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, race-condition

I understand that Race condition: is  when multiple processes (or threads) read and write data items so that the final result depends on the order of
execution in the multiple processes. By my question is **Does the existence of a race condition in the code imply the existence of an execution sequence that will result in a deadlock?**

Comment: Depends on how pedantic you want to be. E.g. if `f()` and `g()` running in close enough proximity provably results in a race condition, but you can prove through the rest of your code that they will never run together, then you'll never see any ill effects from the race condition. At least not until someone changes the code in version 2.0 that suddenly results in both functions running together. Also, there are far more potential ill effects from race conditions than just a deadlock, and, unless locking is involved in the code, deadlock isn't even the most likely problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

A race condition means that depending on execution order, different final results can be observed.

Note: this definition doesn't imply at all that *any* kind of locking happens at all. No locking, no deadlocks. It is as simple as that.

Of course: it is possible that locking is involved; and sometimes you end up with invalid results; and sometimes you end up in a deadlock. But the important thing, as said: it is possible, just not in all cases.